# Making a checkbox exclusive without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm running a Laravel project which has a survey built into it, and I have a question which contains the usual "none of these" answer. When this answer is checked, all other answers should be cleared and disabled.

My JS skills are quite weak as I have only ever used jQuery to enhance frontend elements for PHP projects.

Here is the solution I created using `jQuery`

```
$('[name=q2_5]').change(function(){
    var props = {'disabled': true, 'checked': false};
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('[name=q2_1]').attr(props);
        $('[name=q2_2]').attr(props);
        $('[name=q2_3]').attr(props);
        $('[name=q2_4]').attr(props);
    } else {
        $('[name^=q2_]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cjupnrg/

I would rather not use jQuery in my project as it is proving problematic.

Can this be achieved using plain JS?

Since I am using Laravel, a vue component might be an alternative, but I'm not too familiar with VueJS.

Comment: It can "be achieved in plain JS," what have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery is a JavaScript library, so everything you can do with JQuery can also be done in plain JavaScript.

This is a simple solution for your code in plain JavaScript:

```
let none = document.querySelector('[name=q2_5]');
none.addEventListener("change", onChanged);

function onChanged() {
  if (none.checked === true) {
    document.querySelectorAll('[name^=q2_]:not([name=q2_5])').forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.checked = false;
      checkbox.disabled = true;
    })
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('[name^=q2_]').forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.disabled = false;
    });
  }
}
```